PowerShell and Laravel 11 problem to catch with PUT
I am having problems getting an update from PowerShell... the user has permission to edit that profile... if I send another fake token or another user it detects and warns that they do not have permission but... the value is never saved new in the database... it is only updated to null or an empty string
My Controller:
public function updateDescription(Request $request, $id)
    {
        \Log::info('Request body:', (array)$request->json()->all());

        $company = Company::findOrFail($id);

        // Verificar si el usuario autenticado es el administrador del perfil
        if (Auth::user()->id !== $company->user_id) {
            return response()->json(['message' => 'No tienes permiso para editar esta descripción.'], 403);
        }

        $company->description = $request->description;
        $company->save();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Descripción actualizada con éxito.']);
    }

My PowerShell response:
PS C:\Users\DevZone> Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "http://localhost:8000/api/companies/1/description" -Method PUT -Headers @{ "Authorization" = "Bearer $token"; "Content-Type" = "application/json" } -Body $body


StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : {"message":"Descripci\u00f3n actualizada con \u00e9xito."}
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    Host: localhost:8000
                    Connection: close
                    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
                    Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
                    Cache-Control: no-cache, private
                    Content-Type: ap...
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[Host, localhost:8000], [Connection, close], [Access-Control-Allow-Origin,
                    http://localhost:3000], [Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, true]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {}
ParsedHtml        : mshtml.HTMLDocumentClass
RawContentLength  : 58

my route/api.php
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum'])->put('/companies/{id}/description', [CompanyController::class, 'updateDescription']);

i try too with:
$body = $descriptionObj | ConvertTo-Json

Edit my laravel.log:
[2024-09-20 01:26:18] local.INFO: Request body:  


Are the double-quotes correct here? $company->description = "$request->description"; shouldn't it be $company->description = $request->description;. Also how does the Json body for the PUT request look like?

@SantiagoSquarzon sorry the doble quite is for test whrn try to debug.

Still unclear how should the payload be like and how you're constructing that payload
